# Google Maps - Filter results based on JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

So I have a google map that is pulling in about 185 company addresses and info from a JSON file I have got everything to work but what I want to do is filter the results when you "tick" a radio button or select an option from a select box.

Here is a working plunker - https://plnkr.co/edit/jHCuVVhGDLwgjNw4bcLr

Here is my map code:

```
var map;

function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(58, 16),
        zoom: 2,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
}

var seg = {
    1:'invesCastProd',
    2:'forged',
    3: 'airframe',
    5: 'corp',
    6: 'structurals'        
}

var comp = {
    1:'structurals',
    2:'airfoils',
    3: 'airfoils',
    4: 'wyman',
    5: 'energy',
    6: 'strucComp',
    7: 'mechHard',
    8: 'engineProd',
    9: 'corp',
    10: 'aero',
    12: 'timet',
    13: 'specMetals'
}

$.getJSON("locations.json", function(json1) {
  $.each(json1, function(key, data) {
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.latitude, data.longitude); 
    // Creating a marker and putting it on the map
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLng
    });
    marker.setMap(map);

    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

      if (infoWindow) {infoWindow.close();}
      infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: "<h5>" + data.display_name + "</h5>" +
        "<div>" + data.street+ "</div>" +
        "<div>" + data.city + ", " + data.state + " &nbsp; " + data.postal_code + "</div>" +
        "<div><strong>" + seg[data.segment_id] + "</strong></div>" +
        "<div><strong>" + comp[data.component_id] + "</strong></div>" +
        "<div class='mapPhoneNum'>" + data.telephone + "</div>" +
        "<a href=" + data.web_url + ">Website</a>"
      });
      infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      map.setZoom(15);
      map.panTo(this.getPosition());

    });

    //############################################
    //       I don't know what to add here
    //############################################
    filterMarkers = function(){

    }

  });

});

// Init map
initialize();
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="mapWrap">
  <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  <div class="investCast">
    <select id="pccLoc" onchange="filterMarkers(this.value);">
    <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled" value="">Please select category</option>
    <option class="optGroup" value="corp">PCC Corporate</option>
    <option class="optGroup" value="invesCastProd">Investment Cast Products</option>
    <option class="optChild" value="structurals"> - PCC Structurals</option>
    <option class="optChild" value="airfoils"> - PCC Airfoils</option>
    <option class="optGroup" value="forged">Forged Products</option>
    <option class="optChild" value="wyman"> - Wyman-Gordon</option>
    <option class="optChild" value="energy"> - PCC Energy Group</option>
    <option class="optChild" value="timet"> - Titanium Metals Corp. (TIMET)</option>
    <option class="optChild" value="specMetals"> - Special Metals Corp. (SMC)</option>
    <option class="optGroup" value="airProd">Airframe Products</option>
    <option class="optChild" value="fasteners"> - PCC Fasteners</option>
    <option class="optChild" value="aero"> - PCC Aerostructures</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="mapSelWrap">

  <div class="corpSel optGroup"><input onclick="filterMarkers(this.value);" type="radio" name="loc" value="corp" /> PCC Corporate Headquarters</div>

  <div class="selInnerWrap">
    <div class="selInner">
      <div class="optGroup"><input onclick="filterMarkers(this.value);" type="radio" name="loc" value="invesCastProd" /> Investment Cast Products</div>
      <div class="optChild"><input onclick="filterMarkers(this.value);" type="radio" name="loc" value="structurals" /> PCC Structurals</div>
      <div class="optChild"><input onclick="filterMarkers(this.value);" type="radio" name="loc" value="airfoils" /> PCC Airfoils</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="selInnerWrap">
    <div class="selInner">
      <div class="optGroup"><input onclick="filterMarkers(this.value);" type="radio" name="loc" value="forged" /> Forged Products</div>
      <div class="optChild"><input onclick="filterMarkers(this.value);" type="radio" name="loc" value="wyman" /> Wyman-Gordon</div>
      <div class="optChild"><input onclick="filterMarkers(this.value);" type="radio" name="loc" value="energy" /> PCC Energy Group</div>
      <div class="optChild"><input onclick="filterMarkers(this.value);" type="radio" name="loc" value="timet" /> Titanium Metals Corp.</div>
      <div class="optChild"><input onclick="filterMarkers(this.value);" type="radio" name="loc" value="specMetals" /> Special Metals Corp.</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="selInnerWrap">
    <div class="selInner">
      <div class="optGroup"><input onclick="filterMarkers(this.value);" type="radio" name="loc" value="airframe" /> Airframe Products</div>
      <div class="optChild"><input onclick="filterMarkers(this.value);" type="radio" name="loc" value="fasteners" /> PCC Fasteners</div>
      <div class="optChild"><input onclick="filterMarkers(this.value);" type="radio" name="loc" value="aero" /> PCC Aerostructures</div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

What I am trying to do is create a "filterMarkers" function that runs when you select and option or tick a radio button that filters the pins based on segment_id and component_id (which are just numbers as you can see in the JSON file of the plunk).

And as you can also see in my plunk (https://plnkr.co/edit/jHCuVVhGDLwgjNw4bcLr) in the JavaScript file, I have created two objects ( var = seg{ }, var = comp{ } ) with my "filters" that I have matched up with the numbers in the JSON file. And it is working because when you click on a pin and the info window pops up the text in bold is the filters that are associated with the location. And I have also set the values accordingly to the filters in the HTML elements.

So how can I filter these results now based on the object variables? I am pretty far with this idea and the code I am just stuck on the filtering part.

I just don't even really know what to add into the filter function:

```
filterMarkers = function(){

}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: HI, can you join me in that [forked Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/dACBG6uwIZ82n12GDjm1?p=gitter) ?

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette I'm in there now

Comment: I'm not used to it... Can't you hop in chat in Plunker ? I think i'm in.

Comment: Maybe a [facebook](https://www.facebook.com/bessetteweb/) chat would be easier... I've done some things to your Plunker that I want to show you.

Comment: We should be able to chat inside of stackoverflow :)

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127317/talking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't an easy one to explain...
Nice project, btw.

Here is what I changed from [your Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/jHCuVVhGDLwgjNw4bcLr?p=info), in change order:

1. I moved the Google maps API script call from the `<head>` to the end of the `<html>`.
2. I added `async defer` to it and changed the callback from `initMap` to `initialize`, which is how you named your function.
3. I removed your `initialize()` call at the end of your script. It the API callback's job to trigger it.

This fixed the errors in console.
Then, I got into your question.

4. I added some data attributes to your first radio... Since you want to filter using `component_id` and `segment_id` values from your JSON.

Here it is:

```
<div class="corpSel optGroup"><input onclick="filterMarkers($(this));" type="radio" name="loc" value="corp" data-segment_id="2" data-component_id="13"/> PCC Corporate Headquarters</div>
```

Now in your `filterMarkers = function(category){`, we can retreive those filtering informations.

5. So I wrote this function:

```
filterMarkers = function(category){
    //console.log(category);

    console.log(category.data());
    var component = category.data("component_id");
    var segment = category.data("segment_id")

    // Clear markers
    setMapOnAll(null);
    //marker = [];
    var filteredMarkers=[];

    $.each(myJSON, function(key, data) {
        //console.log(key);

        if( (myJSON[key].component_id == component) && (myJSON[key].segment_id == segment) ){
            console.log("FOUND");

            filteredMarkers.push(key);
        }
    });

    for(i=0;i<filteredMarkers.length;i++){
        myMarkers[filteredMarkers[i]].setMap(map);
    }
}

function setMapOnAll(map) {
    for (var i = 0; i < myMarkers.length; i++) {
        myMarkers[i].setMap(map);
    }
}
```

NOTE: I took the `setMapOnAll(map)` function from the [API documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-remove?hl=fr).

**So the trick is** to remove ALL markers from the map on each radio input click.
A "filtering" loop then checks all json objects to see if the filtering criteria match.

A temporary array (`filteredMarkers`) is created to hold the `myMarkers` array filtered `keys` and use it to redraw the right markers.

[**Updated Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/dACBG6uwIZ82n12GDjm1?p=info)

Comment: absolutely beautiful. This is just what I needed and is working great!